# Bootstrap popover with a link in table header - link doesn't work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, popover

I have a table with popover on the table header. The popover has a link and when I press it, it makes the table sorted and doesn't open the link.

for example:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th> "text"
      <sup data-toggle="popover" data-content="sometext" data-placement='top' data-original-title title> <a href='' data-toggle='modal' data-target='someone'> read more help </a></sup>
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

and so on.The link should open a modal and all it does is sort the table.

Any help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the quick 2-minute tour before posting a question. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

sample codes would be nice.

IIRC, BS tooltip sanitize any HTML codes. You will need to use a template if you want to do basic text.